# how to find corresponding item and value from class list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list, i am trying to find the corresponding item from list.
In list no fix place of the item, some time it comes on 0 place and some time on 1.I am trying below code, so i am looking if usertype is "username" then corresponding value should come in strValue

```
foreach (var item in SignInNames)
{
if (item.Type.Contains("username"))
{
 string strValue =  from a in.SignInNames.Select  
}
}
```

this the deceration of class as

```
 public class test{
     public List<SignInName> SignInNames { get; set; }
    }
    public class SignInName
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
            public string Type { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
            public string Value { get; set; }

            public SignInName(string _value, string _type)
            {
                // Type must be 'emailAddress' (or 'userName')
                this.Type = _type;

                // The user email address
                this.Value = _value;
            }
        }
```

this the data

```
"signInNames": [
        {
            "type": "emailAddress",
            "value": "User2@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "username",
            "value": User2"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results based on those sample inputs.

Comment: `var value = SignInNames.FirstOrDefault(signInName => signInName.Type == "username")?.Value;`

Comment: *I am trying below code* -- OK, but what's wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. all are working :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this?

`var values = SignInNames.Where(s => s.Type.Contains("username"))
    .Select(s => s.Value)
    .ToArray()`

Comment: Why do you need to do "ToArray()" at the end ? Don't think any part of OP requires "ToArray()", or am i missing something here ?

Comment: There are multiple values, based on which matches it can return multiple values. So, either ToArray or First or similar can be used here.

Answer (score 0):

This should return the `Value` of the first `SignInName` with the given `Type`, and return `null` is nothing is found. If you want an empty string returned, just add `?? string.Empty` to the end.

```
public string GetValue(List<SignInName> signInNames, string type) 
  => signInNames.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Type == type)?
                .Select(s => s.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to get respective items from List of SignInName

```
var result = SignInNames.Where(x => x.Type == "username"); //I used == instead of Contains() to get exact results of type username

foreach(var item in result)
  Console.WriteLine($"Value = {item.Value}");
```

using `Contains()`

```
var result = SignInNames.Where(x => x.Type.Contains("username"));

foreach(var item in result)
  Console.WriteLine($"Value = {item.Value}");
```

If your list contain **zero or one** record with type "username", then you can use `FirstOrDefault()`

```
var result = SignInNames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "username");

if(result != null)
   Console.WriteLine($"Value = {result.Value}");
```

From MSDN documentation:

- [Linq Where(predicate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Linq Contains(predicate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Linq FirstOrDefault(predicate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8)